# Check server and notify if there's something new

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, notifications

I'm currently making a news app with Cordova. The app should be able to check a server in the background and notify the user, if there's something new.

I thought I would just use `$.ajax` with jQuery and a Cordova plugin [like this one](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications), but I'm not really sure how to do it.

Can I just set an interval with a function that runs the `$.ajax` command and then the notify function? Because if the app is closed, this won't work any more, or will it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes set interval. I think in this way refresh page

Comment: But if the app is closed, the interval won't work any more

Comment: you have to track with server side code when app clsoed

Comment: that makes no sense. The interval will stop if the app is closed, even if I tell my backend.

Comment: if you want then use third party site like pusher.com

Comment: you probably don't understand what I want.

Comment: Yes I understand. why you are using plugin If you want notification then pusher can handle lot of things...

Comment: without any closed or crash

Comment: because I want the client to check for new updates, NOT a server sending a push message to devices. I don't want to manually send a push whenever something new comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a background task for this kind of job. Background tasks can be cancled by the operating system.

The best way to do it is like stackoverflow does:

If the app is in the foreground, you use sockets.

If the app is in the background, that means from the serversite, the socket connection is broken, the server sends a push notification via one of the notification provider.